# How can I prevent Illustrator from crashing?

Tags: macos, adobe-illustrator

After a while, Illustrator CS6 won't respond and then crashes.

I get this error message:

```
Process:         Adobe Illustrator [875]
Path:            /Applications/Adobe Illustrator CS6/Adobe Illustrator.app/Contents/MacOS/Adobe Illustrator
Identifier:      com.adobe.illustrator
Version:         682 (16.0.0)
Code Type:       X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [232]

Date/Time:       2013-07-08 13:33:48.217 -0400
OS Version:      Mac OS X 10.7.5 (11G63b)
Report Version:  9

Interval Since Last Report:          485322 sec
Crashes Since Last Report:           4
Per-App Interval Since Last Report:  653758 sec
Per-App Crashes Since Last Report:   3
Anonymous UUID:                      8088D751-BE01-47CD-A5BB-DF4AAED08882

Crashed Thread:  0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000000000038

VM Regions Near 0x38:
--> 
    __TEXT                 0000000100000000-000000010186d000 [ 24.4M] r-x/rwx SM=COW  /Applications/Adobe Illustrator CS6/Adobe Illustrator.app/Contents/MacOS/Adobe Illustrator

Application Specific Information:
objc[875]: garbage collection is OFF
```

What can I do to prevent this from occurring?

Comment: You should contact Adobe. This is not really a tech support venue. However, you may consider updating the app. Version 16.0.0 is the *initial* release. There have been at least 4 updates to CS6 since then.

Comment: [Adobe's own forums](http://forums.adobe.com/) are best for this sort of thing. Search around what they've got already. This problem sounds familiar, I think I remember seeing that AI CS6 and CC have had loads of crashing problems related to reading fonts wrong - but I'm no tech support guy, ask the Adobe experts after reading existing threads.

Comment: Also, I know it's a bit late now, but you might be interested in [this bodge to make Illustrator sort-of have an autosave feature](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/13309/3327)